# Well-created struct throwing "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" errors

Tags: c

I have a struct that is throwing "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" errors when I try to access its member functions. I didn't create the struct, my professor did, so I am reasonably sure that when accessed properly it will work perfectly. This is the code:

Pixel.h (Created by professor):

```
#ifndef PIXEL_H
#define PIXEL_H

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BYTES_PER_PIXEL 3

typedef struct
{
        unsigned char R;
        unsigned char G;
        unsigned char B;
}Pixel;
```

Pixel.c (Also created by professor):

```
#include "Pixel.h"

bool readFromFile(FILE* inputFile, Pixel* newPxl)
{
        // Irrelevant code
        return false;
}
```

bmpFilter.c (main file) (Created by me):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Pixel.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        // Irrelevant code, inputFile initialized
        struct Pixel* pix;
        pix = malloc(sizeof(pix));

        pix->readFromFile(inputFile, pix);
}
```

Error:

```
bmpFilter.c: In function ‘main’:
bmpFilter.c:33:5: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Pixel’
  pix->readFromFile(inputFile, pix);
```

The error is almost certainly in bmpFilter and I have been unable to find how to fix it thus far.

Comment: `pix->readFromFile(inputFile, pix);` where is `readFromFile` a member of `pix`?

Comment: Forego the `typedef` and just use `struct Pixel` consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't declare `struct Pixel`. You declared an anonymous struct, and `typedef`ed it as `Pixel` alone. Either change your declaration of the `struct` to:

```
typedef struct Pixel // <-- Added name for struct
{
        unsigned char R;
        unsigned char G;
        unsigned char B;
}Pixel;
```

or when you use it, just declare the variable as:

```
Pixel* pix;
```

Given the definition of `Pixel` comes from your professor (and you're probably not allowed to change it), I'd suggest just changing `struct Pixel* pix;` to `Pixel* pix;` to match the provided code.

Your other problem is that you do `pix->readFromFile(inputFile, pix);`; `pix` doesn't contain a function pointer named `readFromFile` (and even if it did, `malloc`ing the `struct` means the pointer would be garbage). You meant to call the global function:

```
readFromFile(inputFile, pix);  // No pix-> needed
```

Comment: I tried both solutions and got told that the struct has no member readFromFile.

Comment: Ah, missed that error. `readFromFile` is a global function, not an attribute of the struct. Just do `readFromFile(inputFile, pix);`, not `pix->readFromFile(inputFile, pix);`